# Sorting Grand Total column in Pivot Table using google app script in descending order and changing the color of the table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that creates a pivot table with filters based on the range in Mapping tab, all is well but I am having a hard time adding functionality like sorting the pivot table by Grand total in descending order, also some function which changes the color of the table since it is grey when run through script.

here is the script:

```js
function createPivotTable2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var auctionSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Auctions");
  var pivotSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Pivot");
  var mappingSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Mapping");
  
  var range = auctionSheet.getRange("A:P");

  var startValue = mappingSheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var endValue = mappingSheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
  
  var range2 = auctionSheet.getRange("E:E");
  var values = range2.getValues();
  
  var uniqueValues = new Set();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var value = values[i][0];
    if (value >= startValue && value <= endValue) {
      uniqueValues.add(value);
    }
  }
  
  var outputValues = [...uniqueValues];
  outputValues.sort();
  
  var pivotTable = pivotSheet.getRange("A1").createPivotTable(range);
  
  var rowGroup1 = pivotTable.addRowGroup(2); // ProductID
  var rowGroup2 = pivotTable.addRowGroup(4); // productname
  var rowGroup3 = pivotTable.addRowGroup(12); // Prod_Category
  var columnGroup = pivotTable.addColumnGroup(13); // ConditionName
  var valueGroup = pivotTable.addPivotValue(9, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.SUM); // QtyAvailable

  rowGroup2.showTotals(false); // Disable "Show totals" for productname field
  rowGroup3.showTotals(false); // Disable "Show totals" for Prod_Category field

  pivotTable.addFilter(5, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setVisibleValues(outputValues).build());

}
```

and here is a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i6mX4AdO73ySSWpyL4Y8_0piFWj50rUqCbZxHlhAD3o/edit#gid=437977640

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for how to sort a pivot table by a calculated column, descending, with Google app script. I finally have it working. This was the key function that helped: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/pivot-group#sortBy(PivotValue,Object)

I'm building a simple pivot table. Here's my relevant code:

```js
// Add a pivot table
const anchorCell = sheet.getRange("C1");
const sourceData = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1);

const pivotTable = anchorCell.createPivotTable(sourceData);
const pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(1);
const countValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(1, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.COUNTA);

pivotGroup.sortBy(countValue, []); // requires an object as second parameter
pivotGroup.sortDescending();
```